# How to translate “about”?

Tags: preposiciones

I have come across two translations: `acerca de` and `sobre`.

Which one is the most accurate translation for a construct such as “This book is about a cat” or “They are talking about you”?

If they both mean exactly the same thing, are there any preferences around using one over the other in your region?

Comment: Personally, I'd use "Este libro ***se trata de***..." and "Estan hablando ***de***..." in these contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`acerca de` is more literally related to the English concept of `about`, both convey the concept of "near or around", in a figurative (and sometimes literal) sense.

`sobre` usually translates to the English word `on`.

Therefore, as with many phrases and words, you must translate the concept more than the word.

> The book is *about* cats.
>
> He was running *about*.
>
> I'm *about* to leave.

And each of these have multiple possible synonymous expressions in English.

> The book is *on* [the topic of] cats.
>
> He was running *all over the place*.
>
> I'm *nearly ready* to leave.

In Spanish, you see these translations follow more my second set of English phrases:

> El libro es *sobre* los gatos.
>
> Él estuvo corriendo *en todos lados*.
>
> Estoy *a punto* de salir.

So in your specific example, *sobre* is the proper translation of the concept, and in English it's more like saying "on":

> El libro es *sobre* la historia de America. (The book is on the history of America)
>
> El gato está *sobre* la mesa. (The cat is on the table)
>
> ¡No camines *sobre* el pasto! (Don't walk on the grass!)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed lowdown on the prepositions, Flimsy. Really appreciate the time you took to help me out. As for translating the concept instead of the word, well, that exactly was my idea throughout. I was intending to translate the idea of “about” in the sense of “concerning” or “relevant to”.

For example, “This book is about a cat”. Would it be more colloquial to say, “Este libro es sobre un gato” vs. “Este libro es acerca de un gato”? I am asking this because I was listening to a podcast where they did use “acerca de” while I was expecting a “sobre” in that context.

Comment: "sobre" is more common for this context, although "acerca de" is neither unheard of nor incorrect.

Comment: It should be *a punto* instead of *apunto*. I am not allowed to do such a small correction myself, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

And you forgot that `acerca de` can be reduced to just `de`. Here in Spain I think we would translate those sentences this way:

- *This book is about a cat* --> *Este libro trata sobre un gato*
- *They are talking about you* --> *Están hablando de ti*

But other variations are possible and would not be unusual.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Gorpik. Is there any grammatical or colloquial necessity to use **tratar** in your example? How about “_Este libro es sobre un gato_”?

Comment: @AmitSchandillia The verb *ser* cannot be used in that sense. In Spain we might use the verb *ir*: *Este libro va sobre un gato* or *Este libro va de un gato*, but never *Este libro va acerca de un gato*.

Comment: And what about **tratar** in this context?

Comment: Also, you say **ser** is not appropriate in this context. Then what about the following construct in one of the examples provided by _Flimsy_ above: **El libro es sobre la historia de America**?

Comment: *Ser* is sometimes used informally, but it is incorrect. If you check the DRAE, none of the meanings of the verb *ser* match this meaning. I suspect it is just an anglicism.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation on **ser** in this context. I am still not sure I understand the usage of **tratar** in your example sentence: _Este libro trata sobre un gato_.

Comment: It is the same idea behind the word *tratado*, which is a book on a certain subject. The verb *tratar* can be translated as *to deal*. Not only in this context; if you have a deal with someone, you have a *trato*. And an agreement between several countries is a *tratado*.